# How to fix MacBook Pro Display which is not working

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hard-drive, memory, gpu

I guess the reason you clicked this question is that you thought it was the **backlight issue but it is not**. This problem puzzles me.

**ISSUE:** My display does not work.

**What MacBook do I have?**

> **Model**:    MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2011) 
>   **CPU speed**:    2.2 GHz 
>   **CPU Type**: Intel Core i7 (Sandy Bridge) 
>   **CPU Model**:    2675QM 
>   **Cores**:    4 
>   **Bus Speed**:    1333 Mhz 
>   **Turbo Boost**:  Up to 3.3 GHz [Never manually boosted it] 
>   **Installed RAM**:    8 GB (2x4GB) 
>   **RAM Type**: PC3-10600 DDR3 
>   **Hard Drive**:   1TB Seagate Baracuda 
>   **Display Size**: 15.4-inch 
>   **Graphics Card**:    AMD Radeon HD 6750M and Intel HD Graphics 3000 
>   **Card Memory**:  512 MB (AMD) and 384 MB (intel, shared)

**Issues in my MacBook**

- **GPU Failure** like most of the MacBooks from this era.
- **Speaker doesn't work** as I had posted a question about this [before](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346193/how-to-switch-macbook-pro-back-to-normal-digital-audio-out-from-optical-audio-ou) so ***cannot say if the chime is coming or not***.
- The **backlight is doesn't seem to be the issue** cause I've tried to put light through the Apple logo.
- **I've bypassed the GPU by an NVRAM tweak** but when this issue started ***I've mistakenly reset the NVRAM so the computer won't boot to macOS.***
- **Both the fans spin.**
- **The CD Drive make the usual noise.**
- *Since I removed the NVRAM tweak to bypass the GPU now I can't see the apple logo to verify the backlight test so I connected few Bootable pen drives and started Internet Recovery to see the Drive icon and Spinning Globe.*
- Tried **Verbose Mode** to see text for testing the Backlight and ***as always, no a luck***
- **Opened up the back** and **removed the display connector** and reinserted it and… ***you guessed it not luck***.

With these obstacles, I can't really tell what is making this display issue. I really hoped I could give a *bounty* but **my reputation is quite low** but still, I really lost hope in this computer and as a student, I don't think I can fix this computer ever again.

Comment: you need to ask one clearly articulated question, one. All you have here is a bunch of problems and symptoms. Ask your most pressing question ad we'll be happy to assist.

Comment: Thanks, @SteveChambers! As the title of the question suggests my display is not working.

Comment: You need to describe the exact display problem. Unclear: does the display stay dark or distorted (only the latter relates to dGPU problems[of the usual "era" kind])? Concerning the NVRAM: What happens if you just boot from SafeMode or Recovery? Please [edit] additional infos into the Q!

Comment: One thing you could do to improve this is to separate the issues list from the things you’ve tried list. They are both mixed together and it’s a little hard to wrap my mind around.

Comment: Things like "Tried Verbose Mode to see text for testing the Backlight and as always, no a luck" aren't that helpful. What does "no luck" mean exactly: stays black, hangs into the boot process (but some things are visible: either the backlight alone [subtle brightness changes], the graphical logo, verbose text…) // If it doesn't stay pitch-black: how far do you get with verbose mode, RecoveryMode, or SafeMode? Describe exactly the state you arrive at.

Comment: You clearly say "your display does not work."  How do you know this?  Everything you've described points to a logic board that has given up the ghost.  The way you test to see if this is the case is to remove your display and connect it to a known working logic board (I'm confident it's fine).  The 2011 MacBook Pros were riddled with problems; it's time to put this one out of its misery.